# Does Express.js not `res.send` Sets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, set

I have a `set` that I create in node.js and I am trying to send it to the client with `Express.js` using `res.send` or `res.json` but the set always appears empty on the client side.  This is my code:

```
app.get('/test-endpoint', function(req, res) {
    let set1 = new Set();
    set1.add('SOME ITEM');
    console.log('Set 1:', set1);  // logs out set1 correctly in the terminal (Set 1 Set: { 'SOME ITEM' })

    res.json(set1);  // when this gets to the client side it is an empty set ({})
});
```

Why is this happening?  Is it an Express.js issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't send a raw set. You could try this though: `res.json(Array.from(set1));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Express `response.json` function uses `JSON.stringify` to send the data. And because `JSON.stringify` ignore all Symbols-keyed properties in addition to functions . That's why you receive an empty object on the client.

Check more info of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ prop: 5, foo() {}, [Symbol('s')]: 'symbol' }));
// -> "{"prop":5}"

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Set([1, 'two', null])));
// -> "{}"
```

Comment: You can also review the `express.response` implementation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js).